# Is it possible to have a param array of Func's

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern

Is something like the following construct possible?

```
  public IQueryable<T> AllWithFetch<TRelated>(IQueryable<T> existing, params Expression<Func<T, TRelated>>[] fetchExpressions)
  {
     return fetchExpressions.Aggregate(existing, (current, exp) => current.Fetch(exp));
  }
```

Which could then be called like this...

```
var allDetails = this.preGrantDetailRepository
                .AllWithFetch(this.preGrantDetailRepository.All, x => x.Case, x => x.CaseOwner)
```

Basically I am trying to include the addition of fetching strategies for NHibernate to our abstract repository, to enable us to specify these strategies from our logic layer without breaking the repository pattern. For example if we changed from NHibernate to another ORM we can then provide the same repository methods but implemented for that ORM.

The problem appears when I try to chain on more than one func in the param array.

So this works...

```
var allDetails = this.preGrantDetailRepository
                .AllWithFetch(this.preGrantDetailRepository.All, x => x.Case)
```

But this fails with "the type arguments cannot be inferred from their usage" messge

```
var allDetails = this.preGrantDetailRepository
                .AllWithFetch(this.preGrantDetailRepository.All, x => x.Case, x => x.CaseOwner)
```

I'm using .NET 3.5, Repository Pattern, Fluent NHibernate, SQL Server 2008

**EDIT**

I solved the problem in the with help from Porges answers below, so I have acepted it. The problem did come from an incorrect use of TRelated. Here is the working method in the repository...

```
public IQueryable<T> AllWithFetch<T>(IQueryable<T> existing, params Expression<Func<T, Entity>>[] fetchExpressions)
        {
            return fetchExpressions.Aggregate(existing, (current, exp) => current.Fetch(exp));
        }
```

It is now AllWithFetch not TRelated and I am using the super class of the two entities (Case & CaseOwner) in the Func.

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: What are the return types of `.Case` and `.CaseOwner` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `TRelated`, this isn't anything to do with `params` specifically.

Try this, for example:

```
void DoSomething<T,U>(Func<T,U> f, Func<T,U> f2)
{
}

void Main()
{
    DoSomething((int x) => x + 1, (int x) => x + ""); 
}
```

The compiler will infer that `T` must be `int`, but it cannot infer a good type for `U` (I'm not sure of the *exact* details, but it generally won't look for a type higher up the inheritance chain).

To get it to work, you need to specify the superclass; in this case, `object`:

```
void Main()
{
    DoSomething<int,object>((int x) => x + 1, (int x) => x + ""); 
}
```

So you'll either need to specify a superclass yourself (which looks like it will be `object` here), or just get rid of the `TRelated` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should have TRelated as the return value for each func. Do .Case and .CaseOwner have the same type? If no, you can use

```
Func<T, object>
```

instead (or any interface)